# Using, if applicable, the subclass' method

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
public class A {
    private boolean val(){
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean test(){
        return val();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private boolean val(){
        return false;
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.test());
    }
}
```

It returns true because the test() method in A calls A's val(). After some research, I understood that this is expected in Java. However, I would like test() to print false when called from B, and true when called from A.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code calls `A`'s `val()` and not `B`'s `val()` is that the `val()` method has `private` access modifier and therefore cannot be overridden. Change the access modifier to `protected`.

```
public class A {
    protected boolean val(){
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean test() {
        return val();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    protected boolean val() {
        return false;
    }
}
```